# Is there any way for auto run a script after it raises an error

Tags: python

I have a python script that is working 24/7 and sometimes it raises an error and then stops working. I want to know is there any way to restart the script after the crash?

I tried a simple program that stopped with a zerodivision error and used many methods off the internet but none of them worked : this is sample code :

```
_list = [30,15,12,2,9,7,8,4,53,6,5,1,5,8,19,5,0]
for a in _list:
    x = 2/a
    print(x)
```

and the error is :

```
0.25
0.10526315789473684
0.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restart.py", line 29, in <module>
    x = 2/a
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Please update your question with at least one of the methods you have tried to fix this with.

Comment: error is clear, you need to skip the `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for a in _list:
    try:
        x = 2/a
        print(x)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, sometimes your code is trying to divide by `0` in:

```
x = 2/a
```

This is however impossible, so Python gives you an error. To fix this you could either check whether `a` is a zero, or catch the exception and pass. I think the first method is better because this exception is avoidable. So here are the two solutions:

**1. Check whether `a` is zero**

```
for a in _list:
    if a is not 0:
        x = 2/a
        print(x)
```

**2. Try/Catch the ZeroDivisionError**

```
for a in _list:
    try:
        x = 2/a
        print(x)
    except (ZeroDivisionError):
        pass
```